# matlab - fix wrong complicated structure

Tags: matlab, structure

I have this structure with paths stored in columns. For constellation 3 I have longer and shorter paths between points 1 and 2 with the first two being:

`const(3).path{1,2}=[1,1;  9,10;  7,8;  6,6;  2,2];`

I would like to add another path that is shorter:

```
const(3).path2{1}=[1;9;7;3];
const(3).path{1,2}(:,end+1)=const(3).path2{1};
```

The whole code is:

```
for i2 = 1:Num.paths
 if const(k).path{const(k).path2{i2}(1),const(k).path2{i2}(end)}>0
  const(k).path{const(k).path2{i2}(1),const(k).path2{i2}(end)}(:,end+1)=const(k).path2{i2};
  else
  const(k).path{const(k).path2{i2}(1),const(k).path2{i2}(end)}=const(k).path2{i2};
  end
 end
```

I understand the error but don't know how to change the structure in order to keep all paths stored where they belong.
The error is:
Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 5-by-1 and the size of the
right side is 4-by-1.

Comment: Do you want `const(3).path{1,2}=const(3).path2{1};` ? Or do you want `const(3).path{1,2}=[const(3).path{1,2} ;const(3).path2{1};]` ?

Comment: Oh, wait, you want a matrix with less rows in one column than the other? You can not do that.

Comment: and how do I solve this, can I further complicate the structure?

Comment: I assume so. Just make more cells/fields...

Comment: I am not sure how easy it would be to access const(3).paths{1,2}.path1

Comment: Access by whom? You know **exactly** how easy/hard it is to access: `const(3).paths{1,2}.path1` like this. If you are wondering if its better to rethink your problem and find a better way? possibly, but we don't know with the information shared.

Comment: `const(3).path{1,2}(:,end+1)=const(3).path2{1};` would have to be turned into `const(3).path{1,2}.path3=const(3).path2{1};` and how would a loop access it since I can no longer use `end`

Comment: By doing `size` and not using `end`. Yes, that looks complex and I would refactor that code, but I insist, I can not tell you how, its your project